# Servicenow script infinite recursion

Tags: servicenow

I have the following ServiceNow script which inserts the record into live_message table.

```
(function executeRule(current, previous/*null when async*/) {


  var requestBody;
  var responseBody;
  var status;
  var request;
  var response;

  try {

    request = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2("LiveMessageWebhook", "post");

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    var parameters = "&chat_message=" + current.chat_message.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&context=" + current.context.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&formatted_message=" + current.formatted_message.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&has_attachments=" + current.has_attachments.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&has_links=" + current.has_links.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&has_tags=" + current.has_tags.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&ID=" + current.id.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&in_reply_to=" + current.in_reply_to.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&isLiked=" + current.is_liked.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&lastActivity=" + current.last_activity.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&lastMessage=" + current.last_message.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&likeCount=" + current.like_count.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&message=" + current.message.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&next_reply_order_chunk=" + current.next_reply_order_chunk.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&order=" + current.order.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&poll=" + current.poll.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&private=" + current.private_message.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&profile=" + current.profile.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&reflected_field=" + current.reflected_field.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&reply_to=" + current.reply_to.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&state=" + current.state.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&group_type=" + current.sys_class_name.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&created_by=" + current.sys_created_by.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&created_on=" + current.sys_created_on.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&domain=" + current.sys_domain.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&domain_path=" + current.sys_domain_path.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&sys_ID=" + current.sys_id.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&to_profile=" + current.sys_domain.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&updates=" + current.sys_mod_count.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&updated_by=" + current.sys_updated_by.toString();
    parameters = parameters + "&updated_on=" + current.sys_updated_on.toString();

    request.setRequestBody(encodeURI(parameters));
    var l = request.getRequestBody();
    response = request.execute();

    responseBody = response.haveError()
      ? response.getErrorMessage()
      : response.getBody();
    status = response.getStatusCode();
    {
      var gr = new GlideRecord('live_message');

      gr.initialize();
      gr.chat_message = current.chat_message;
      gr.context = current.context.toString();
      gr.formatted_message = "abc";
      gr.group = current.group;
      gr.has_attachments = current.has_attachments;
      gr.has_links = current.has_links;
      gr.has_tags = current.has_tags;
      gr.id = current.id;
      gr.in_reply_to = "admin";
      gr.is_liked = current.is_liked;
      gr.last_activity = current.last_activity;
      gr.last_message = current.last_message;
      gr.like_count = current.like_count;
      gr.message = "abc";
      gr.next_reply_order_chunk = current.next_reply_order_chunk;
      gr.order = current.order;
      gr.poll = current.poll;
      gr.private_message = current.private_message;
      gr.profile = current.profile;
      gr.reflected_field = current.reflected_field;
      gr.reply_to = current.reply_to;
      gr.state = current.state;

      gr.sys_class_name = current.sys_class_name;
      gr.sys_created_by = current.sys_created_by;
      gr.sys_created_on = current.sys_created_on;
      gr.sys_domain = current.sys_domain;
      gr.sys_domain_path = current.sys_domain_path;
      gr.sys_mod_count = current.sys_mod_count;
      gr.sys_updated_by = current.sys_updated_by;
      gr.sys_updated_on = current.sys_updated_on;
      gr.to_profile = current.to_profile;
      gr.insertWithReferences();

    }

  } catch (ex) {
    responseBody = 'Exception: ' + ex;
    status = '900';
    requestBody = request
      ? request.getRequestBody()
      : null;
  } finally {
    gs.info("Final: Request Body: " + requestBody);
    gs.info("Final: Response: " + responseBody);
    gs.info("Final: HTTP Status: " + status);
    gs.addInfoMessage('Final: Finished');
  }

})(current, previous);
```

But after inserting the record it again goes back to the try block again and does the whole thing again and now with the inserted record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is this business rule configured? 
Is it possible that the changes made **by** this script, could also **trigger** the script to run?

Here's an example of what I mean: 
Imagine I have a business rule that executes whenever a record in the table "u_arbitrary_counter" is updated. 
Imagine that the function of this business rule is that whenever such a record is updated, we increase the value of the "u_counter" field by one, like so:

```
current.setValue('u_counter', parseInt(current.getValue('u_counter')) + 1);
current.update();
```

By using `.update()`, I'm forcing an update to the database, EVEN if this is a "before" business rule.

> **Pro Tip:** Note that "before" business rules run on the data that's about to be
>   saved to the database, BEFORE the actual database operation has taken
>   place. Any changes to the "current" object in a "before" business rule
>   will be saved **even without** using current.update, because you're
>   modifying the data that's about to be sent to the database anyway, in
>   the natural course of this operation.

So using current.update() in a BEFORE business rule isn't a great idea. For the same reason though, performing any other operation which necessarily leads to a database update which could trigger this same business rule is a bad idea. It doesn't have to be `current.update()` -- Instead, imagine if rather than updating the current record, I did something like...

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('u_arbitrary_counter'); //the same table this BR is running on
gr.initialize();
gr.setValue('u_counter', parseInt(current.getValue('u_counter')) + 1);
gr.insert(); //This triggers a database action!
```

This is no good for the same reason. 
Ditto for any REST calls which would trigger a DB action on this table which may trigger this business rule.

---

### The solution

If this is indeed the cause of your issue (and without knowing the configuration of your business rule, I can't be sure if it is or not), there is actually a way to tell the system not to run any further business rules as a result of the operation your script performs. Right before your `gr.insertWithReferences();` line (line 91), IF that block of code is the issue (which I'm fairly confident it is), add:

```
gr.setWorkflow(false);
```

This prevents business rules from running. 
Unfortunately, since you're placing the record into the live_message table, that **may** not be a good idea either, since the messenger may require some business rule to propagate or present that information once inserted; I'm not sure. 
If that is the case, I would recommend adding a condition to your business rule so that it only runs under certain circumstances, and then craft your inserted record to **not** meet those criteria.

> **Pro Tip:** PS - I notice you access a table field using `current.field_name.toString()` in some places, and directly access
>   `current.field_name` in others. While the former is acceptable (not
>   that I recommend it in most cases), the latter should almost never be
>   used -- except in the case of journal fields. Instead, I strongly
>   recommend using the appropriate getter/setter methods, to avoid
>   pass-by-reference issues and confusion, and to ensure you're not
>   relying on JavaScript's coersion, which doesn't always play nice with
>   Mozilla Rhino, which ServiceNow runs on the back-end. [Example issue
>   here](https://community.servicenow.com/thread/233473).  For more info, please see [my article on using getValue()
>   and setValue() in ServiceNow](http://snprotips.com/blog/2017/4/9/always-use-getters-and-setters).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I found out about the filter conditions so as to when to run the script and it works and also thanks for telling regarding gr.setWorkflow() it's really handy.

Comment: @RickySterling can u tell me what is the filter condition? I am also Facing similar issue..

Comment: @Raghvendra.....the script should run only when in_reply_to is undefined